# Pair Objective in SQL (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a question concerning returning a pair "objective" such that some demand has been met. The example can be simply depicted here in a (n*3) Matrix as below.

The goal is to find a pair of product (group by ID) that has the least cost. Single row (ID) would be just neglected from the analysis. Of course, if the pair appears multiply, that would be taken account in form of the sum in costs.

```
ID  Product Cost
1   a   2
1   b   3
2   c   4
3   d   5
3   b   6
4   a   6
4   b   5
4   d   4
5   c   3
6   a   2
```

That would mean that (a,b) is a pair to be considered in ID = 1, (d,b) is a pair considered in ID = 3, (a,b) appears once again in ID = 4, so does (b,d). However, ID = 4 also accounts for another pair which is (a,d) appearing only once in the whole table. The sequence of the pair does not matter. Thus I sum the cost of the two (a,b) pairs and (b,d) pairs to compare the cost value and whether (a,b),(b,d) or (a,d) is cheaper. Of course, the cost of the pairs within, has to be summed as well.
The goal is to return the pair products that has the least cost. At our examples the results would be:

```
(a,b) = 5(ID = 1) + 11 (ID = 4) = 16
(b,d) = 11 (ID = 3)  + 9 (ID = 4) = 20
(a,d) = 10 (ID = 4)
```

Solution : (a,d) as the optimal pair. Note, that there are cheaper solutions when I only consider single variables instead of pairs variables, but this is not the objective. I am seeking for a pair within a column, that reflects the least cost.

I hope that my question is clear for everyone, and I hope that it is possible to help me out of my query. Many thanks in advance!

Best,

David

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want a self-join and aggregation.  The self-join generates all pairs of products for each `id`.  The aggregation calculates the sum of costs for them:

```
select top 1 t1.product, t2.product, sum(t1.cost + t2.cost)
from t as t1 inner join
     t as t2
     on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.product < t2.product
group by t1.product, t2.product
order by sum(t1.cost + t2.cost);
```

Comment: This one: `and t1.product < t2.product` will not work in Access. Solution: move the condition to the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Hi, many thanks for the tipp that has helped me a lot. One more thing is that I would like to display all the "pair" costs and not only the lowest one. My intention is to select the lowest one at the end with eyeball, by Access should return all the pair cost in one column. What modification has to be done then?

Comment: @user20280 . . . Remove the `top 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. There is one more issue concerning the task: I want to display the ID number that the pairs belong to, would it then be select ..., ID then at the end group by ... ID? But then, the results I had before, are different.

Comment: You cannot easily do that in MS Access, because there is no function to concatenate together multiple values.

Comment: What kind of difficult way does there exist to display the relevant ID if I really want to solve it? Would another inner join loop help?

Comment: @user20280 . . . You can add `min(id)` to the `select` to get one of the ids.